# How to edit the fig with the new mplfinance package

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I can't seem to add any text, rotate axis, change the background color, etc with the new mplfinance.

With the old mpl-finance, I just do `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and edit the fig and ax however I want to like: `fig.text(0.96, 1, 'some text', size=9, fontweight='bold',color='black', ha="right")` or `plt.legend( loc='upper left')`

Does anyone know how to do that with the new package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To gain access to mplfinance's Figure and Axes objects, there are two ways:**

---

**Method 1.** Set `returnfig=True` when calling plot:

`fig, axlist = mpf.plot(data,...,returnfig=True,...)`

`axlist` will be a list of axes corresponding to the [**panels**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb) from top to bottom, ***two axes per panel*** where the first is the *primary* axes and the next is the _secondary axes.  For example, if you have 3 panels then `returnfig=True` will return 6 Axes objects.   `axlist[0]` and `axlist[1]` will be the primary and secondary axes, respectively, for panel **0**.  `axlist[2]` and `axlist[3]` will be the primary and secondary axes, respectively, for panel **1**, etc.

---

**Method 2.** Create your own Figure and Axes objects and pass these into mplfinance.  [**You can see examples of how to do this here.**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb)

---

**Please note also** that, when specifying x,y coordinates for positioning of text, legends, etc. then:

if `show_nontrading` kwarg is `False` (i.e. the default value if unspecified) then the **x-axis values are not actually dates** as they appear, **but are integer values from zero up to the number of rows** in your dataframe.

HTH