# How to change font size and font type in mplfinance title

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, title, mplfinance

I have the following code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
df = web.DataReader('goog','yahoo', start="2021-07-3", end="2021-09-12")
mpf.plot(df, style='charles', type = 'candle', volume=True, figratio=(12,8), title = "new title \n another title")
```

[image]

Could you please advise how can i change the font and size of newline `another title` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As per [How to edit the fig with the new mplfinance package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61547880/7758804), use `returnfig=True` to extract the `fig` and a list of `axes` objects.
- Then use standard `matplotlib` methods to add an `axes title` and a `figure suptitle`, because `title` in `mpf.plot` is actually the `figure suptitle`, not the `axes title`.
- References:

  - [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html)
  - [`matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html)
  - [`matplotlib.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) for text properties like `style`

```py
df = web.DataReader('goog','yahoo', start="2021-07-3", end="2021-09-12")
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df, style='charles', type = 'candle', volume=True, figratio=(12,8), returnfig=True)

# add a new suptitle
fig.suptitle('Figure Title', y=1.05, fontsize=30, x=0.59)

# add a title the the correct axes
axlist[0].set_title('Axis Title', fontsize=25, style='italic', fontfamily='fantasy', loc='center')

# save the figure
fig.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Slartibartfast You're welcome. Glad this works for you.

Comment: Could you please answer 1 more question. If i want to suppress the plot from being plotted in spyder/jupyter and just be saved how can i do that. Reason is `RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory.`

Comment: Try `fig.clf()` after saving