# Changing mplfinance chart styling when "returnfig=True" is not being accepted anywhere in the code

Tags: python, matplotlib, styling, mplfinance

I am trying to change the axis titles and font size in multiple charts that are plotted using mpf.plot and fig.add_axes to place them on screen.

I have understood the process and examples given in this link [How to change font size and font type in mplfinance title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210734/how-to-change-font-size-and-font-type-in-mplfinance-title) and on the github discussing the approach, but it will not work with my code. Anywhere I put "returnfig=True" it causes errors.

Here is my code snippet of the relevant section

```
fig = mpf.figure(figsize=(12,8),style='yahoo')

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.70,0.3,0.25]) # ax = fig.add_axes([left,bottom,width,height])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.65,0.3,0.05])

ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.70,0.3,0.25])
ax4 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.65,0.3,0.05])

ax5 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.70,0.3,0.25])
ax6 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.65,0.3,0.05])

ax7 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.25,0.3,0.25])
ax8 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.20,0.3,0.05])

ax9 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.25,0.3,0.25])
ax10 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.20,0.3,0.05])

ax11 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.25,0.3,0.25])
ax12 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.20,0.3,0.05])

mpf.plot(ausd,type='candle',ax=ax1,volume=ax2, mav=(9), show_nontrading=False, axtitle='M6A=F')
mpf.plot(gbpf,type='candle',ax=ax3,volume=ax4, mav=(9), show_nontrading=False, axtitle='M6B=F')
mpf.plot(cadf,type='candle',ax=ax5,volume=ax6, mav=(9), show_nontrading=False, axtitle='M6E=F')
mpf.plot(btcf,type='candle',ax=ax7,volume=ax8, mav=(9), show_nontrading=False, axtitle='M6C=F')
mpf.plot(gldf,type='candle',ax=ax9,volume=ax10, mav=(9), show_nontrading=False, axtitle='MBT=F')
mpf.plot(slvf,type='candle',ax=ax11,volume=ax12, mav=(9), show_nontrading=False, axtitle='MGC=F')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that `returnfig=True` is required if you want to access each of the panels when they are set up. My understanding may still be lacking. If you set up a subplot with additional axes, I don't think you need `returnfig=True`. Completing the graph with the ticker in the previous question would result in the following code. I introduced loop processing, shortened the long date format, and reduced the orientation of the ticker.

```
myTickers = ['M6A=F','M6B=F','M6C=F','M6E=F','MBT=F','MGC=F']
fig = mpf.figure(figsize=(12,12), style='yahoo')

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.70,0.25,0.25]) 
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.60,0.25,0.08])

ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.70,0.25,0.25])
ax4 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.60,0.25,0.08])

ax5 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.70,0.25,0.25])
ax6 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.60,0.25,0.08])

ax7 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.25,0.25,0.25])
ax8 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.15,0.25,0.08])

ax9 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.25,0.25,0.25])
ax10 = fig.add_axes([0.36,0.15,0.25,0.07])

ax11 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.25,0.25,0.25])
ax12 = fig.add_axes([0.68,0.15,0.25,0.08])

for i,(t,ax) in enumerate(zip(myTickers,[[ax1,ax2],[ax3,ax4],[ax5,ax6],[ax7,ax8],[ax9,ax10],[ax11,ax12]])):
    dff = df.loc[:,t]
    mpf.plot(dff, type='candle',
             ax=ax[0],
             volume=ax[1],
             mav=(9),
             show_nontrading=False,
             axtitle=t,
             datetime_format='%b %d',
             xrotation=30)
    
for ax in [ax1,ax3,ax5,ax7,ax9,ax11]:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
```

[image]

Comment: That solves what was going to be my next question of how to loop the code better and how to format the date (my 5-min charts have time as well), so thank you.

I was actually looking for ways to format the styling e.g. font, size, color and plot background color, etc...

Comment: in the code where you write "for i,(t,ax) in enumerate(zip(myTickers...." how would you change that if you had 12 myTickers but only wanted the first 6?

Comment: I use a list limited to 6 tickers out of 12 tickers to handle the tickers and the axis to be expanded in a loop process, but to handle them in a loop process, you can do the following. `for i,(t,ax) in enumerate(zip(myTickers[:6],[[ax1,ax2],...)`

Comment: See here for a [detailed description](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/styles.ipynb) of how to customize graph styles.

Comment: That link helped with some additional changes. I also found a workaround through using bespoke chartstyles and rcparam like this -
`myrcparams={'axes.labelsize':'x-small','axes.titlesize':'small'}` and then 
`mystyle = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpf_style='yahoo', marketcolors=chartColors, rc=myrcparams)`

I was then able to add style in using `fig = mpf.figure(figsize=(12,8), style=mystyle)` 

The only thing left to figure out how to do is remove the duplicate date info from the x-axis of the charts.

Comment: In response to comments from the mplfinance developer, we have also addressed how to remove the date of the remaining issues. This is now complete, including your additional modifications. code and graph updated

Comment: thanks was perfect. one little tweak... I added this bit of code to lock in the x-axis as the volume charts tended to drift

```ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.70,0.3,0.25])```
```ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.60,0.3,0.05], sharex=ax1)```

unfortunately with the additional code to remove the labels that you added, the ```sharex=ax1``` also forces the effect on both ax1 and ax2 even if specify only removing the labels from one.

```for ax in [ax1,ax3,ax5,ax7,ax9,ax11]:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])```

Answer (score 3):

The are ***two ways*** to gain access to the Figure and Axes objects that mplfinance uses.  [**These two ways are documented here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects).

**1.** If you use **`returnfig=True`** it means that **`mpf.plot()`** *is creating the Figure and Axes objects internally, and returning them to you for further manipulation* before *you* eventually call `mpf.show()` or `fig.savefig()` to complete the plot.

**2.** However, if you create ***your own*** Figure and Axes objects ***externally*** to `mpf.plot()`, *even if you use `mpf.figure()`* to create the Figure object, then **`mpf.plot()`** does ***not*** own the Figure and Axes objects, and so cannot return them to you!
***In fact, you already have them and own them** so there is no point to returning them!*  This is why, when `mpf.plot()` detects that you have passed Axes into it (thus it is in "External Axes Mode") then it will reject the kwarg `returnfig` because in that context it doesn't make any sense to return a Figure and Axes that you already have.

Comment: Your explanation gave me a deeper understanding of the external axis.

Comment: I had worked to that linked document originally, but found by using `fig.add_subplot` I was unable to get multiple charts to work in the way you see in the code above, but by using `fig.add_axes` it did work. In the comments above I noted that I found a workaround to styling and all but the ability to remove labels from axes. At this point my choice is to scrap the entire code and go back to trying to use `fig.add.subplot`  which I spent a day failing to get working, or solve that last puzzle of how to remove axes labels with my current code, albeit the "discouraged" method.

Comment: You said "returning them to you for further manipulation before you eventually call mpf.show() or fig.savefig() to complete the plot." - I was using `plt.show()`, I assume this is the same thing when coding outside of notebooks?

Comment: Yes, `mpf.show()` is the same as `plt.show()` as you can [see here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/_mplwraps.py#L31-L33).  The idea is that, by providing `mpf` versions of some of the pyplot functions, then many mplfinance users are able to do a variety of manipulations without ever having to `import matplotlib.pyplot`